# How to show banner ad in specific screen only in flutter

Tags: android, flutter, dart, admob, ads

I am making a app in which I want to show ad in the settings screen. I have successfully added the ad but I don't want to keep showing the ad when I am done with the settings portion. Please help me out with this. I am attaching the pics.[image: First Half of Code]
[image: Other half of code]

Comment: Don't post text as image

Answer (score 1):

When you dispose of the page, you need to dispose of the banner ad also as its rendered as a native component on the flutter page. Change the widget to `Stateful` and dispose of it in SettingScreen itself.

```dart
@override
void dispose() {
    myad?.dispose();
    super.dispose();
}
```

Comment: I've tried this but this disposes only once. Is there any way to just dispose it every time when the user leaves the screen where the ad was shown. Thanks

Comment: You only need to dispose of when user goes out of the screen where you are displaying the ad